# Strange Error occurance in Erlang rfc4627

Tags: erlang, yaws, rfc4627

```
    {ok,RequestData,_} = rfc4627:decode(Arg#arg.clidata)
```

When it match the Output of

```
    rfc4627:decode(Arg#arg.clidata)
```

to

```
    {ok,RequestData,_}
```

it gives a {badmatch, ....} error

But I Copied the output in the error msg and matched to

```
    {ok,RequestData,_}
```

in a erlang shell, Then it matches without any error.

This error only happens randomly. I can't figure out a reason. Sometimes it match and code works without any error. And sometimes it gives a error and yaws code crashes.

This is the error msg

```
    <h2>Internal error, yaws code crashed</h2><br /><hr />
    <pre>

    ERROR erlang code threw an uncaught exception:
    File: /usr/local/var/yaws/www/prime/yaws/session.yaws:1
    Class: error

    Exception: {badmatch,{ok,{obj,[{"action",<<"GET_SESSION_INFO">>}]},[]}}
    Req: {http_request,'POST',{abs_path,"/prime/yaws/session.yaws"},{1,1}}
    Stack: [{session,handle,2,
             [{file,"/root/.yaws/yaws/default/session.erl"},{line,30}]},
    {yaws_server,deliver_dyn_part,8,
                 [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2801}]},
    {yaws_server,aloop,4,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1215}]},
    {yaws_server,acceptor0,2,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1052}]},
    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]
    </pre><hr />
```

Comment: Please help me if someone knows what is happening....???

Comment: Please try  `{ok, _RequestData, _}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the issue. I have 2 different interfaces in same server and both of them uses the same file with the same file name. but code inside is bit different. that's the problem. when I go to one interface it dynamically compiles the yaws and create an erl file in a temporary path. Then if I try to go to the other interface it does not compile the yaws again instead it refers the same erl file from the other interface because both files have the same name. The error occurs when it tries to match the request data comes from the interface. because that 2 interfaces send request data in 2 different formats.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it is clear that value returned from `rfc4627:decode/1` should easily match with three-tuple. So that's not the problem

Your issue might be with pattern matching with some "other" variable in function call.  Especially if you have `RequestData` defined earlier, than with your code you would just compare previous value with this returned from `rfc4627:decode/1`.

It is also worth mentioning that while `_` will pattern-match to anything (or will not pattern match if you will), the variables starting with underscore (like `_Reminder`) **will** pattern match (they just won't give you warnings if they are unused).

#### Edit

If you look at `=` operator in Erlang it could mean two different things. Either it could be assignment or pattern match, or both in your case (what you are trying to do is pattern match on `ok` atom, and at the same time assign new value to `RequestData`).  So, depending on `ReqestData` being bound or not (already having some value, or not) you will have different behavior.

I'm **assuming** that `ReqestData` already is bound when you call `{ok,RequestData,_} = rfc4627:decode(Arg#arg.clidata)`. In that case, we just pattern match (compare) value returned by `decode` and assigned to `ReqestData`, which can either pass or fail. For example it could be bound to `null` or `false`, which are the values that could be returned by `decode`. And since it all depends on data you are getting outside of your system, it could explain sometime passing/sometime failing behaviour.

Comment: Yes I Understand all the facts you have given. But how could the same code give an error at one time and work without an error at other times. That's the thing I don't understand.

Comment: I've edited my original message, because I could not fit my response into comment limit.

If something is still not clear please share the rest of your code (whole function). At this point I'm assuming and guessing, and maybe if I could pin-point error in your code my explanation would be clearer.

Comment: Finally I've found the issue. I have 2 different interfaces in same server and both of them uses the same file with the same file name. but code inside is bit different. that's the problem. when I go to one interface it dynamically compiles the yaws and create an erl file in a temporary path. Then if I try to go to the other interface it does not compile the yaws again instead it refers the same erl file from the other interface because both files have the same name.